# Connection failed whene i'm try to migrate my pg database using knex

Tags: postgresql, docker

I'm tryin to migrate my DB using knex and postgres in database.

docker-compose.yml

## docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3.1"

services:
  db:
    image: "postgres:latest"
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - ./docker-data/db-data:/var/lib/postgresql
    environment:
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: ${POSTGRES_PASSWORD}
      POSTGRES_USER: ${POSTGRES_USER}
      POSTGRES_DB: ${POSTGRES_DB}
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
  adminer:
    depends_on:
      - db
    image: adminer
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
```

knexfile.js

```
require("dotenv").config();

module.exports = {
  development: {
    client: "pg",
    connection: {
      database: process.env.POSTGRES_DB,
      user: process.env.POSTGRES_USER,
      password: process.env.POSTGRES_PASSWORD
    },
    migrations: {
      directory: "./db/migrations"
    }
  }
};
```

$ npx knex migrate:latest

Output:

```
error: authentification password to user admin 
    at Connection.parseE (C:\Users\Youssef\Desktop\Home\projects\restaurant-app\server\node_modules\pg\lib\connection.js:600:48)
    at Connection.parseMessage (C:\Users\Youssef\Desktop\Home\projects\restaurant-app\server\node_modules\pg\lib\connection.js:399:19)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Youssef\Desktop\Home\projects\restaurant-app\server\node_modules\pg\lib\connection.js:115:22)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:321:20)
    at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:305:12)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:280:11)
    at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:214:10)
    at TCP.onStreamRead (internal/stream_base_commons.js:186:23)
```

I'm stack here any one can help me.

more info:

os: windows 7

Comment: Dockerfile? Compose file? Docker command? Post your setup.

Comment: @Stefan Golubović  I added it.